# even odd status checker grid view using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a gridview where user enters some integer number in a text box and via using jquery function I have to display even/odd in another text box of the same row. Please see the example, there are other columns in the grid view but I have omitted all of them.

```
ID      ITEMNAME        REVIEW      
1       CUBE BOX        4           EVEN
2       G CUBE BOX      7           ODD
3       SHELL BOX       3           ODD
4       G SHELL BOX     8           EVEN 
...
```

Here `REVIEW` column contains two text box, in the first text box will input integer text and corresponding to that text EVEN/ODD will be displayed in the next text box.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ReviewGrid">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S No." ItemStyle-Width="8%">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                                        
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="REVIEW">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <input type="text" runat="server" id="review_val" class="review_val"/>
               <input type="text" runat="server" id="status_val" readonly="true" class="status_val"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

jquery script

```
$(".review_val").change(function () {
    $(".status_val").val(evenodd($(this).val()));
});
```

Here I am using class value but it's not working as desired. I need to retrieve the id of each row individually but when I did inspect element of the text boxes, I found that id of every text boxes are dynamic i.e., row number is attached with each text box. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do $(".status_val") because that applies to all statusvalues on the whole page.

You will need to use a relative search, possibly $(this).next().val('evenodd')

```
$(".review_val").change(function () {
    $(this).next().val(evenodd($(this).val()));
});
```

If your text boxes are in a different column you will need to either, a) give the textbox a unique ID, eg "review_2" and give the textbox a data property

```
data-rowid="2"
```

then you can do

```
$(".review_val").change(function () {
    var rowId = $(this).data("rowid");
    $("#review_" + rowId).val(evenodd($(this).val()));
});
```

Alternatively, you can use .closest("td") to find the current table cell, and then use .next() to move to the next td, and use a selector to find the label/textbox to set the evenodd value.

I prefer the ID option, because it doesn't rely on the DOM structure

Comment: What if text boxes are of different columns I mean first textbox in REVIEW column and second text box in STATUS column. How can I retrieve values then?